# Creating Cosine Function with Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, trigonometry

I Would like to create a function in Matlab that takes the parameters: A,w0,omega,n1,nf

```
function A*cos(wb*n + omega) =fcosine(A,w0,omega,n1,nf)
n=n1:nf;
wb = w0;
xb = A*cos(wb*n + omega);
subplot(4,1,2), stem(n, xb)
grid
end
```

i am struggling doing it right, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function xb = fcosine(A, w0, omega, n1, nf)
    n = n1:nf;
    wb = w0;
    xb = A*cos(wb*n + omega);
    subplot(4,1,2), stem(n, xb)
    grid
end
```

But you should re-think about your [Matlab function design](https://sites.google.com/site/matlabstyleguidelines/naming-conventions/functions#TOC-Functions-with-no-output-argument-or-which-only-return-a-handle-should-be-named-after-what-they-do).